# what is difference of template and users in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In `crypto-config.yaml` for each organization we have `Template` and `users`, I know `template` number is the number of users but I can't understand what `Users` variable is used for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `template` is used to refer to the number of `peers` that you want to have in an organization. Peers are the units which store the `ledger`. It is completely different from the type of `users` who update these ledgers. So maybe that is the difference between a `template and user`.